# Dirac delta confusions

Tags: integration, derivatives, dirac-delta

I might be hitting the wall and would appreciate following me on this.

Some explain dirac delta such as it's 0 everywhere except at a single point where it's infinite and some explain it as a infinitely narrow spike.

**Contradiction 1:** It seems to me that these 2 descriptions contradict each other, because infinitely narrow spike is not the same thing as "0 everywhere except at one point where it's non-zero". The reason they're not the same is infinitely narrow spike still suggests that it's non-zero for more values of $x$ than for just only one value($x=0$).

**Contradiction 2**: Another reason of contradiction is that if it's only non-zero at a single point and zero everywhere else, then its integral can NOT be 1.

**Question 1:** Well, I'm sure you will say that dirac delta is not a function which I have read many times. Then why can't we just get rid of the explanation - "it's zero everywhere except at one point" ?

**Question 2:** I somehow didn't understand what we mean: "it's a distribution or generalized function", because I don't know what either of these 2 concepts are.

Would appreciate if you could explain it in simple terms.

Comment: It's neither, being a distribution, and these questions are both answered plenty of places elsewhere already. The spike idea is known as an approximation to the identity, and converges weakly to the delta distribution. The point idea encodes the delta function as a measure supported on a single point. You have to know some analysis to understand this topic. Do some reading on these topics and rework your questions to be much more specific.

Comment: I mean, spike idea should be the actual, correct definition than $\delta(x) = 0 x \neq 0, \delta(x) = \infty, x=0$, because integral can only be 1 by using spike idea. This is my main confusion

Comment: "infinitely narrow spike still suggests that it's non-zero for more values of $x$
 than for just only one value" Which other values would that be?

Comment: If something is infinitely narrow(imagine you draw it on a graph), then it's non-zero for $x$ values infinitely close to 0. @Arthur

Comment: "Infinitely close to $0$" doesn't exist in standard analysis (the real numbers are [Archimedean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property)). So that's a non-issue until you start to work with actual infinitesimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Question 1:**
The reason why bizzare definitions of a so called delta "function" can be found everywhere (especially in engineering and physics) has probably two reasons:

The first is historic: A fully satisfactory theory was only finished in the 1950s by Laurent Schwartz, but it is complicated and so it is often inacessible to many scientists who have to use it.

Secondly many people in physics and engineering use heuristics, in which case pretending as if there was a delta function works suprisingly well.

**To Question 2:**
The dirac $\delta$ is not a function. So in particular it is neither an "infinitesimal spike" nor a function that is $0$ everywhere except $0$ (and infinite at $0$).

I will try my hand at explaining the Dirac $\delta$ without delving to deep into the details:

Let $F$ be the vector space of all functions $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Then we define the dirac $\delta$ by
$$
\begin{align}
\delta : F &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
f &\longmapsto f(0)
\end{align}
$$
Notice that $\delta$ is a linear map from $F$ to the real numbers. So $\delta$ is not a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, but a linear map $F \to \mathbb{R}$.

It is a common abuse of notation to write $\int \delta (x) f(x)dx $ for $\delta (f)$. It is important to understand that the first expression is just a notation for the later (and not actually an integral).

Often we restrict $\delta$ to some subspace of $F$. Such subspaces are often called "test functions". See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Definitions_of_test_functions_and_distributions) for some commonly used subspaces of $F$. A distribution is then a (continuous) linear map from the test function space to the real/complex numbers (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Distributions)).

Now suppose we take a "narrow spike at 0 function" $\varphi_{\varepsilon} : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ whose width we control with the parameter $\varepsilon>0$. To be precise, i want $\varphi_\varepsilon$ to be a so called mollifier (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Definition)). Further suppose that
$f$ is a "nice" function (say differentiable and zero outside of some finite interval).
Then we have
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int \varphi_\varepsilon (x) f(x) dx = f(0) = \delta (f).
$$
Note that the map $f \mapsto \int \varphi_\varepsilon (x) f(x) dx $ is also a linear map sending "nice" functions to real numbers. Lets call it $\tilde{\varphi}_\varepsilon$.
So we have shown above that $\tilde{\varphi}_\varepsilon$ approximates the Dirac $\delta$ as $\varepsilon$ gets small. Notice that its not the spike function that approximates the Dirac $\delta$, but the linear map  $\tilde{\varphi}_\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks so much for such great answer. So basically, $\delta$ is a map to which we give "input" which is a function($f(x)$) and output is a number. $f(x)$ is a test function.  Then what is $\delta (x)$. I think it's a "narrow spike" function, right  ?

Comment: @Giorgi $f$ is a function, not $f(x)$, $ f(x)$ is a number (the value of $f$ at $x$). $\delta(x)$ is not well defined (unless $x$ were a function), you cant feed numbers to $\delta$. $\delta$ eats functions and gives back numbers. So you can write $\delta(f)$, which is the value of delta at $f$, but not $\delta(x)$ (when $x  \in \mathbb{R}$ is a number).

Comment: Ah, yes, What I meant was people write $\delta(x)$ inside the integral and that's what was causing too much confusion. How can something be inside an integral and that something be called a mapping lol.

Comment: I think $\varphi_\varepsilon$ is a spike function then, right ?

Comment: @Giorgi Yes $\varphi_\varepsilon$ is a spike function.  Yes it is very confusing, but if we write an integral like $\int \delta (x) f(x) dx$, then that simply means $\delta(f)$. The $\delta(x)$ in the integral has no real mathematical meaning, its just a notation.

Comment: So I think we say $\delta(x)$ is 0 for every non zero x, and infinite for $x=0$, that's actually not $\delta(x)$ but a spike function.

Comment: My confusion is that your very last lines where you say "notice" and "approximation".

Comment: I think I can't really understand what "$\tilde{\varphi}_\varepsilon$  approximates $\delta$" means :(

Comment: What I understand is this: the $\delta$ is mapping and described such as: $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int \varphi_\varepsilon (x) f(x) dx = \delta (f)$ (note that mapping includes $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}$ as well and this is what you called $\tilde{\varphi}_\varepsilon$. So when we say it's 0 everywhere except one point, which behaves like that?(spike function, or mapping), but mapping can't because mapping's output is $f(0)$ which is real number

Comment: @Giorgi "when we say it's 0 everywhere except one point" i never said that, so i do not understand what you are refering to here? $\tilde{\varphi}_\varepsilon$ approximates $\delta$ means that for all "nice" functions $f$ we have  $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \tilde{\varphi}_\varepsilon (f) = \delta (f)$.

Comment: Maybe I didn't catch exactly what $\delta (f)$ and $\tilde{\varphi}_\varepsilon$ is. So just to repeat, $\delta$ is a mapping whose input is $f(x)$(test function) and whose output is $\int \varphi_\varepsilon (x) f(x) dx$.  What did you call $\tilde{\varphi}_\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: @Giorgi No. $\delta$ is a mapping whose input is a function $f$ and whose output is $f(0)$. $\tilde{\varphi}_\varepsilon$ is a mapping whose input is a function $f$ and whose output is $\int \varphi_\varepsilon (x) f(x) dx$.

Comment: ah, I think I get it. and in real problems, if If I realize that my problem description consists of such a function which is a spike function and somehow, I see that i end up with integral where i have product of spike function + some other test function, then I can immediatelly see dirac in play and use $f(0)$, right ?

Comment: Thanks soooooo much. I think I can spend some time to understand this more. finally, great explanation so far ! <3 life saver. pretty burnt out now, so have to sleep ASAP, I might ask you 1 or 2 questions tomorrow if you don't mind, but after I re-read your answer thoroughly once again. Thanks again

Comment: hey @jd27 hope you doing good. after lots of looking into this, I ended up with these questions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814845/clarifications-about-dirac-delta would appreciate your input so much